# Python console classifies my output result as tuple instead of list

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

Whenever I use the `find_match_column()` function, the python console show me that all result is a tuple,even though they look like list to me. What should I do to make the result become list?

My Text file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18tYvYs43vA7ib3br1h1VD75OUU5ho1u8/view?usp=sharing

MY Code:

```
def opentext():
    allinstall = open("save_all_install.txt", "r",encoding="UTF-8")
    return allinstall
def find_match_column(new_search_words,ent1,ent2):
    search_words = ["'Happy'"]

    replaced_list = [w.replace("'Happy'", '{}'.format(new_search_words)) for w in search_words]

    result = []
    for line in opentext():
        if any(word in line for word in replaced_list):
            # Get the front Publisher Part
            k = line.split('\n')[0]
            # Get the Position I want for exact Column
            entry=k[int('{}'.format(ent1)):int('{}'.format(ent2))].split(',')
            # print(entry)
            result.append(entry[0])
              
    print(result)
    return new_search_words,ent1,ent2 # If not return will show NONE type.

# I want the output should be a list can use for me.

find_match_column("'DisplayName'",17,-5)
find_match_column("'Publisher'",15,-5)
find_match_column("'DisplayVersion'",20,-5)
find_match_column("'InstallDate'",17,-5)
find_match_column("'InstallSource'",19,-5)
find_match_column("'InstallLocation'",21,-5)
```

**Example:Result by Python Console if I put `type(find_match_column(XX))`**:

```
<class 'Tuple
```

**Screenshot of running the `find_match_column()` function:**
[image]'>

Comment: `return [new_search_words,ent1,ent2]` or `return list(new_search_words,ent1,ent2)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help,it works.

Answer (score 1):

you return multiple values which will always be returned as a tuple.

```
return new_search_words,ent1,ent2 # If not return will show NONE type.
```

will return

```
(new_search_words,ent1,ent2)
```

You might want to return your result instead?

```
return result
```